# I want to edit the text of a specific file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I would like to modify the configuration file, as shown below.
What can I do as a shell script ?

### before

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "calibration"
        MatchProduct    "Touch"
        Option  "Calibration"   "166 3939 186 3814"
        Option  "SwapAxes"      "1"
        Option  "InvertX"   "on"
        Option  "InvertY"   "on"
EndSection
```

### after

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "calibration"
        MatchProduct    "Touch"
        Option  "Calibration"   "166 3939 186 3814"
        Option  "SwapAxes"      "1"
        Option  "InvertX"   "off"
        Option  "InvertY"   "on"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or even

```
sed -i '/InvertX/s/"on"/"off"/' file_name
```

Comment: won't that act on Option rather than "on"? modified command: `sed -i '/InvertX/s/"on"/"off"/' file_name`

Comment: @spasic Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: @spasic Yes, it would turn `Option` into `Optioff`.

Comment: Ah, now I get it.

Comment: alternatively, `sed -i  '/InvertX/ s/on/off/2' filename` to change only the **second** occurence of `on` to `off`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's:"InvertX"   "on":"InvertX"   "off":g' file_name
```